# Angular $httpBackend test doesn't capture $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular's `$httpBackend` for unit testing a bunch of API functionality. The application makes use of `$resource` for most API endpoints, but has a single raw `$http` call (to send data along with a DELETE request, not my choice).

The model has a simple delete method like this:

```
this.delete = function(target) {
  return $http({method: 'DELETE', url: '/api/delete' + this.id, data: target});
};
```

And a simple test case, which fails with `No pending request to flush`:

```
it('calls the API', function() {
    httpBackend.expect('DELETE', '/api/delete').respond(200, '');
    scope.obj.delete(1);
    httpBackend.flush();
});
```

This test setup seems to work fine with any endpoints using `$resource`, but fails as soon as I use `$http`. I verified that the `.delete()` method has been called, and that it returns a `promise` as expected.

Did I miss something in the documentation?

Comment: Your url doesn't match. Use regex instead.

Comment: it's a typo in the example

Comment: So, correct your example.

Comment: `'/api/delete' + this.id` doesn't match `'/api/delete'`